# Inserting array into xml file

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm, function, text

does anyone know, how can I insert data from my double-dimension int array to XML file, which I already created? (I am going to use XML file as a source to GridView)

file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<file>

</file>
```

and my array[5][5]

```
int[][] array = new int[5][5]{
{0 1 3 4 2},
{1 0 4 2 6},
{3 4 0 7 1}
{4 2 7 0 7},
{2 6 1 7 0}
};
```

Anyone can help me to figure out how I can do this?

Comment: So how your output xml will be look like?

Comment: I don't know exactly, never used xml files before, I think something like <1>0</1> <2>1</2> <3>3</3>.... something like that I guess

Comment: What tags do you want?  You could create a datatable and the use the DataTableWriteXml() method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to put data into datatable and then use WriteXml method :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Array");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col_A", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col_B", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col_C", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col_D", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col_E", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0, 1, 3, 4, 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 0, 4, 2, 6});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, 4, 0, 7, 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4, 2, 7, 0, 7});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 6, 1, 7, 0});

            dt.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

        }
    }
}
```